# Lock in mysql database

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking

My schema 'test' has 3 tables: 'user', 'post' and 'revision'.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`user` (
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`post` (
  `idpost` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `content` VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
  `revision_count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idpost`),
   INDEX `fk_post_user1_idx` (`iduser` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_post_user1`
     FOREIGN KEY (`iduser`)
     REFERENCES `test`.`user` (`iduser`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`revision` (
  `idrevision` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `idpost` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `content` VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE INDEX `index1` (`idpost` ASC, `idrevision` ASC),
   PRIMARY KEY (`idrevision`, `iduser`),
   INDEX `fk_revision_user1_idx` (`iduser` ASC),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_revision_post`
     FOREIGN KEY (`idpost`)
     REFERENCES `test`.`post` (`idpost`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
   CONSTRAINT `fk_revision_user1`
     FOREIGN KEY (`iduser`)
     REFERENCES `test`.`user` (`iduser`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And there is the script creates data:

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (`iduser`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Ann');
INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (`iduser`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Bob');

INSERT INTO `test`.`post` (`idpost`, `iduser`, `content`, `revision_count`) VALUES (1, 1, 'this is first post', 1);

INSERT INTO `test`.`revision` (`idrevision`, `iduser`, `idpost`, `content`) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'this is old content of first post');
```

I create 2 sessions work concurrently. Session 1 works with query:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO revision (idrevision, idpost, iduser, content) VALUES  
  ((SELECT max_idrevision + 1 
    FROM (SELECT max(idrevision) AS max_idrevision
          FROM revision WHERE idpost = 1) AS anon_1), 
   1, 2, 'abc xyz');
```

Now session 2 works:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE revision SET idrevision=3 WHERE idpost=1 AND iduser =1;
-- will hang by lock

-- but with this update
UPDATE revision SET content='nwe asdfs' WHERE idpost=1 AND iduser=1;
-- not hang
```

I don't know what's lock mysql used with query insert in session 1? Is it row lock or table lock or anything else ?